# Rendering ReactJS Component within Laravel 5.4 View

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, render, babeljs

I would like to ask for some help with Rendering ReactJS Component within Laravel 5.4 View as per Title and it doesn't need to be blade. I don't need the Component to be pre-rendered on server side I just want to display it. I'm using gulp with babel (es2015 and react presets) to transpile the component and the task completes fines resulting a valid js. I've tried what most of people suggested which was creating a div with id and then trying to render the component to it but that doesn't seems to work.

**Component's Content:**

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

import React, { Component } from '/node_modules/react';
import ReactDom from '/node_modules/react-dom';

class ContactForm extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return (<form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input name="name" className="form-control"/>

                    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
                    <input name="email" className="form-control"/>

                    <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                    <input name="subject" className="form-control"/>

                    <label for="message">Message:</label>
                    <textarea name="message" className="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" className="btn btn-warning btn-md pull-right" value="Send It"/>
                </div>
            </form>)
    }

}

export default ContactForm;

if (document.getElementById('contact-form')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<ContactForm />, document.getElementById('contact-form'));
}
```

**Element within view:**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <div id="contact-form"></div>
</div>
```

**Error within the console:**

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at contactform.js:3

When I declare exports variable as suggested in one of the posts I found 
before loading any JS within view then the error would appear and disappear after a second

Just in case you find it useful here is a whole component transpiled

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

var _react = require('/node_modules/react');

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _reactDom = require('/node_modules/react-dom');

var _reactDom2 = _interopRequireDefault(_reactDom);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; } /*jshint esversion: 6 */

var ContactForm = function (_React$Component) {
    _inherits(ContactForm, _React$Component);

    function ContactForm(props) {
        _classCallCheck(this, ContactForm);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (ContactForm.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(ContactForm)).call(this, props));
    }

    _createClass(ContactForm, [{
        key: 'render',
        value: function render() {
            return _react2.default.createElement(
                'form',
                null,
                _react2.default.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'form-group' },
                    _react2.default.createElement(
                        'label',
                        { 'for': 'name' },
                        'Name:'
                    ),
                    _react2.default.createElement('input', { name: 'name', className: 'form-control' }),
                    _react2.default.createElement(
                        'label',
                        { 'for': 'email' },
                        'E-mail:'
                    ),
                    _react2.default.createElement('input', { name: 'email', className: 'form-control' }),
                    _react2.default.createElement(
                        'label',
                        { 'for': 'subject' },
                        'Subject:'
                    ),
                    _react2.default.createElement('input', { name: 'subject', className: 'form-control' }),
                    _react2.default.createElement(
                        'label',
                        { 'for': 'message' },
                        'Message:'
                    ),
                    _react2.default.createElement('textarea', { name: 'message', className: 'form-control' })
                ),
                _react2.default.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { 'class': 'form-group' },
                    _react2.default.createElement('input', { type: 'submit', className: 'btn btn-warning btn-md pull-right', value: 'Send It' })
                )
            );
        }
    }]);

    return ContactForm;
}(_react2.default.Component);

exports.default = ContactForm;


if (document.getElementById('contact-form')) {
    ReactDOM.render(_react2.default.createElement(ContactForm, null), document.getElementById('contact-form'));
}
```

I would be really grateful for any suggestions and help. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to add that the transpiled JS is included in view. At the moment it only shows blank space in place where component should load.

Comment: I don't think the es2015 preset supports export. I usually just use babel-preset-stage-0.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion but as much as it makes sense it didn't solve the problem. I've got past the error with exports by following heidipowers suggestion here: https://github.com/JeremyEnglert/JointsWP/issues/249 and installing  ES2015 modules to UMD transform then using it in my gulp task but still my problem persists and component doesn't render.

Comment: I have just noticed that another error started appearing in console and it's Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined
    at contactform.js:131
    at contactform.js:10
    at contactform.js:13

Comment: You don't need "/node_modules/" in your imports. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Brad but I actually do need it as that's the location of modules I installed through npm and it needs to be explicitly specified or else my IDE (PHP Storm) complains that path cannot be resolved which is right. I did try it though just for the sake of it and result would be same but I suppose it's for different reasons.